# Fields returning null value with view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to make an adapter for a viewpager and to pass some data in the adapter but my fields are returning null values.

CarFragment.java

```
private static final String CAR_NAME = "car_name";
private static final String CAR_DESCRIPTION = "car_description";

private String mCarName;
private String mDescription;

public static CarFragment newInstance(String carName, String description){
    CarFragment fragment = new CarFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(CAR_NAME, carName);
    args.putString(CAR_DESCRIPTION, description);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public CarFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args != null){
        mCarName = args.getString(CAR_NAME);
        mDescription = args.getString(CAR_DESCRIPTION);

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_tour, container, false);

    TextView carField = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.car_name);
    TextView carDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.car_description);
    carField.setText("Naam : " + mCarName);
    carDescription.setText("Beschcrijving : " + mDescription);

    return v;
}
```

I think the error is coming from my adapter. This is where the data gets picked up.

I have two cases for the viewpager. There are two pages. In the first one i want to show object(0) and the other one object(1). The viewpager is working and the application doesn't crash. However it seems like my data flow is not correct. In carfragment it should display the data that i am picking up from the JSONobject.

```
JSONObject data;
JSONArray car;

public String carName ;
public String description ;

public String CAR_NAAM;
public String CAR_DESCRIPTION;

public CarAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void onEvent(CarResponse reponse) throws JSONException {
    data = reponse.getData();
    car = data.getJSONArray("carList");

    JSONObject firstCar =  car.getJSONObject(0);
    CAR_NAAM = firstCar.getString("name");
    CAR_DESCRIPTION = firstCar.getString("description");

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            coffeeName = CAR_NAAM;
            description = CAR_DESCRIPTION;


        case 1:
            carName = CAR_NAAM;
            description = CAR_DESCRIPTION;

    }
    return CarFragment.newInstance(carName, description);
}
```

I hope the problem is clear and you can help. If more details needed please feel free to ask.

Comment: where are you calling onEvent ?

Comment: "I think the error is coming from my adapter" You could research this by logging what you receive and / or output from your adapter. Would be nice to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I understand the error. The first thing that the adapter does public fragment getItem. It doesn't listen to the response first. You have an idea how to make it run the onEvent first?

Comment: @AndroidTestor if you using GreenRobot EventBus , you cant rely that onEvent will be called first